# AttributeError: module 'authentication.views' has no attribute 'ajax_load_messages'

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am creating a clone twitter application for a project, very basic. no styling. As i started to implement a Direct Messaging. i encounter a problem. with the urls.py file.

it seems to want a view of my ajax_load_messages from within authentication but i put that view within the chat app itself.

i am unable to run server. what can i do to solve this?
[Image of urls.py file with error msg and directory visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPYhJ.png)

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, copy-paste your code snippet and the console output here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try `ajax_load_messages` instead of `views.ajax_load_messages`.

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('<int:pk>/',inbox,name='inbox'),
     path('ajax/<int:pk>/',ajax_load_messages,name='inbox_load_messages'),

]
```

note that it is always better to use a unique name for every url.